# Flow: How to type an object with variable number of keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am building an object dynamically with this:

```
getObject = () => {
  const data = [
    {field1: 'val1', field2: 'val2'},
    {field1: 'val3', field2: 'val4'}
  ]

  const res = {}

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    res[i] = data[i]
  }

  return res 
}
```

My actual issue is more complex, but this simple case shows my problem.

So I get an object that looks like this:

```
{
  0 : {field1: 'val1', field2: 'val2'},
  1:  {field1: 'val3', field2: 'val4'}
}
```

I know its keys are numbers and I the keys' values are 
`{ field1: string, field2: string }`, but I don't know the number of keys, since it depends on the array length.

How can I type the returned object with Flow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need smth like that

```
const data: { [index: number]: {field1: string, field2: string} }
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps

Answer (score 2):

you can use Objects as maps in flow

```
// @flow
var o: { [number]: {field1: string, field2: string} } = {};
o[1] = {field1: 'hello', field2: 'world'};
o[2] = {field1: 'hello', field2: 'world'};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the object's key, you can do `Object.keys(obj)`.

This will give you the exact number of keys the `obj` has.

Comment: I am trying to create a flow type, a dictionary